# Orderby Meta Value and Query from Meta Query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

The following query is returning blank with no errors and I'm not sure why.

**Query Arguments:**

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'      => 'games' ,
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'  => 'and',
        array(
            'key'   => 'custom_post_id',
            'value' => get_the_id()
        ),
        array(
            'key'   => 'second_post_id',
            'value' => get_the_id()
        )
    ),
    'meta_key'      => '_game_name',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'         => 'ASC'
);
```

Why will this query not run?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the get_the_id() portion...

Comment: In which scope are you calling this? In a loop?

Comment: It's the arguments for a standard WP_Query. It's not in another loop if that's what you mean.